# Regarding input for creating circles using center coordinates

Tags: java, arrays, input, graphics, drawing

Hello I was given an assignment in which I have to draw 3 circles using their center coordinates and radii which is input by the user. The assignment specifically states that I must input the center and radius, I cannot input the x and y coordinates separately. They must be input as a coordinate pair (x,y).
Here is my code.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Circles {

static Scanner CONSOLE = new Scanner(System.in);

public static final int PANEL_HEIGHT = 300;
public static final int PANEL_WIDTH = 400;

public static void main (String [] args) {

DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel (PANEL_HEIGHT,PANEL_WIDTH);
Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
System.out.println();

System.out.println("Red Circle data");
System.out.println("Input center of Red circle: ");
   int center1 = CONSOLE.nextInt();
System.out.println("Input radius of Red circle: ");
   int radius1 = CONSOLE.nextInt();
System.out.println();

System.out.println("Blue Circle data");
System.out.println("Input center of Blue circle: ");
   int center2 = CONSOLE.nextInt();
System.out.println("Input radius of Blue circle: ");
   int radius2 = CONSOLE.nextInt();
System.out.println();

System.out.println("Green Circle data");
System.out.println("Input center of Green circle: ");
   int center3 = CONSOLE.nextInt();
System.out.println("Input radius of Green circle: ");
   int radius3 = CONSOLE.nextInt();

g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.fillOval(center1 -radius1 ,center1-radius1 ,radius1 ,radius1);

g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
g.fillOval(center2 -radius2 ,center2-radius2 ,radius2 ,radius2);

g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
g.fillOval(center3 -radius3 ,center3-radius3 ,radius3 ,radius3);


    }
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to properly input and store the x and y coordinates as one int. As it is currently it just takes one data point, stores it, and uses it as both x and y.

```
System.out.println("Red Circle data");
System.out.println("Input center of Red circle: ");
   int center1 = CONSOLE.nextInt();
```

Here is where I know java must ask for the values and store them.

```
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.fillOval(center1(THIS SHOULD BE THE X VALUE) -radius1 ,center1(THIS SHOULD BE THE Y VALUE)-radius1 ,radius1 ,radius1);
```

Then here I have to somehow get the values stored in the above code.

Please help i'm kinda new to this and would appreciate some feedback! Hope what im asking for makes sense! :S

Answer (score 0):

not JAVA coder so I stick to C++, **are you sure you want x,y pair in single int ?**

1.**If yes then just encode it**

- but you must know the coordinates range
- for example if you have 32bit int and your coordinates fits to 16 bit then:

  ```
  int xy,x,y;
  xy = (x&0x0000FFFF) | ((y&0x0000FFFF)<<16); // this makes xy = (x,y)
  ```

and if you need to unpack the data again do:

```
    x= xy     &0x0000FFFF; if (int(x&00008000)!=0)  x|=0xFFFF0000;
    y=(xy>>16)&0x0000FFFF; if (int(y&00008000)!=0)  y|=0xFFFF0000;
```

- the if at the end restores the missing bits for negative numbers ...

2.**if in single variable instead then use**

- array:

  ```
  int xy[2],x,y;
  xy[0]=x;
  xy[1]=y;
  ```
- or struct/class

  ```
  int x,y;
  struct point { int x,y; } xy;      
  xy.x=x;
  xy.y=y;
  ```